# Hessian with large binary file

Tags: java, hessian

how to create file Upload/Downlod  servlet using Hessian binary protocol? for files larger than 1GB. I create test for [Hessian with large binary data](http://hessian.caucho.com/doc/hessian-overview.xtp#Hessian%20with%20large%20binary%20data), but if file is more than available RAM size exception is thrown java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.

//api for client

```
public interface Upload {
  public void upload(String filename, InputStream data);
}
```

//implementation

```
public class Upload extends HessianServlet implements Upload {
  @Override
  public void upload(String fileName, InputStream in) {
    int count = 0;
    try {
      while ((count = in.read()) != -1) {
        System.err.print("reading view in console=" + count);
      }
      in.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Upload.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.err.print("total buffers filled=" + count);
  }
}
```

//client call

```
    HessianProxyFactory proxy = new HessianProxyFactory();

    try {
```

//call proxy for Upload

```
      Upload x = (Upload) proxy.create(Upload.class, "http://localhost:8080/PathToServletFile/Upload");

      InputStream in;

      try {
        in = new FileInputStream("C:/bigFile.zip");
        x.upload("some file", in);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HessianFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HessianFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

//Exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2786)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:94)
at sun.net.www.http.PosterOutputStream.write(PosterOutputStream.java:61)
at com.caucho.hessian.io.HessianOutput.writeByteBufferPart(HessianOutput.java:743)
at com.caucho.hessian.io.AbstractHessianOutput.writeByteStream(AbstractHessianOutput.java:407)
at com.caucho.hessian.io.InputStreamSerializer.writeObject(InputStreamSerializer.java:70)
at com.caucho.hessian.io.HessianOutput.writeObject(HessianOutput.java:324)
at com.caucho.hessian.io.HessianOutput.call(HessianOutput.java:132)
at com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianProxy.sendRequest(HessianProxy.java:280)
at com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianProxy.invoke(HessianProxy.java:170)
at $Proxy0.upload(Unknown Source)
at hessianlargefiletest.HessianFrame.btnDownloadActionPerformed(HessianFrame.java:108)
at hessianlargefiletest.HessianFrame.access$000(HessianFrame.java:32)
at hessianlargefiletest.HessianFrame$1.actionPerformed(HessianFrame.java:56)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6289)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6054)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4652)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
```

Comment: It appears this should work. ore you sure you are not trying to process the entire input in memory. i.e. are you sure your reader doesn't keep the data it reads in memory.

Comment: code looks like above. is it correct?

Comment: Hmmm, the stack trace looks like it is copying the data into a ByteArrayOutputStream. From the docuemntation, it looks like you are doing it right, but the library doesn't behave in an ideal manner.  I suggest you are the original developers. ;)

Comment: You can report this bug at http://bugs.caucho.com

Answer (score 0):

you should not use Proxy to send large files

as the [hessian document](http://hessian.caucho.com/doc/hessian-overview.xtp#Hessianwithlargebinarydata) says:

> the client needs to **take control of the Hessian protocol directly**, because the proxy interface would require buffering the entire file before the call returns.

so , you could try this (i haven't test it)

```
public interface Download {
    public InputStream download(String filename, InputStream data){
          //create your http connection and get the outputstream
          OutputStream os = ....;

          Hessian2Output out = new Hessian2Output(os);

          out.writeObject(filename);
          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          int c = -1;
          while( (c = data.read(buf)) != -1) {
             os.write(buf);
          }
          os.flush();
          //.....
    }
}
```